Why is my UI not getting updated using StreamBuilder?
I am uploading an image, storing it in storage, and then the downloard url is then stored in Firebase Firestore. The update in Firestore takes place successfully, however, my UI is not being updated, while using a StreamBuilder. I don't get any error, the only issue is that my UI is not getting updated as I intended to.
Code Snippet as follows:
body: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    },
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                      ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(snapshot.error);
                    return const Text('Something went wrong');
                  } else if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                      snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                    return const Text('No data available');
                  } else {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 75,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          widget.userData.profileImage.toString()),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
              Positioned(
                  left: 107,
                  top: 107,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border:
                            Border.all(width: .7, color: Colors.white),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 143, 7)),
                    child: Center(
                      child: IconButton(
                          color:
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 250, 250, 250),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

                            String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now()
                                .millisecondsSinceEpoch
                                .toString();

                            XFile? file = await imagePicker.pickImage(
                                source: ImageSource.gallery);

                            if (file == null) return;

                            final image = await file.readAsBytes();

                            Reference referenceRoot =
                                FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
                            Reference referenceDirectory =
                                referenceRoot.child('UserImages');
                            Reference referenceImageToUpload =
                                referenceDirectory
                                    .child(uniqueFileName);

                            try {
                              await referenceImageToUpload
                                  .putData(image);
                              imageUrl = await referenceImageToUpload
                                  .getDownloadURL();
                              debugPrint('ImageUrlReceived');

                              UserModel newUserData = widget.userData
                                  .copyWith(profileImage: imageUrl);

                              await newUserData.updateFirestore();
                            } catch (error) {
                              debugPrint('Some error occured');
                              debugPrint(error.toString());
                            }
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.edit)),
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),


The image is being referred to the correct location. If I logout and come back to this page again, I am getting the updated image.
Also, just thinking if snapshots is reflected for all files downstream of 'users' collection? Should I have to be more specific and call the document?
The UserModel is as follows:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    required this.selfRef,
    required this.mail,
    required this.name,
    this.profileImage =
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png',
  });

  final DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> selfRef;
  final String mail;
  final String? name;
  final String? profileImage;

  factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.data();
    return UserModel(
        selfRef: snapshot.reference,
        mail: data!['mail'] as String,
        name: data['name'] as String,
        profileImage: data['profileImage'] as String? ??
            'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png');
  }
  Map<String, Object?> toMap() => <String, dynamic>{
        'mail': mail,
        'name': name,
        'profileImage': profileImage
      };

  Future<void> updateFirestore() async {
    return await selfRef.set(toMap());
  }

  UserModel copyWith({
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>? selfRef,
    String? mail,
    String? name,
    String? profileImage,
  }) {
    return UserModel(
      selfRef: selfRef ?? this.selfRef,
      mail: mail ?? this.mail,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      profileImage: profileImage ?? this.profileImage,
    );
  }
}


What does this code do/look like: newUserData.updateFirestore()?

Map<String, Object?> toMap() => <String, dynamic>{
'mail': mail,
'name': name,
'profileImage': profileImage
};
Future updateFirestore() async {
return await selfRef.set(toMap());
}

Instead of posting that in a comment, please edit your question (there's a link right under). I'd also recomment (re)reading how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example, as following the guidance in there giveds you the best chance that someone can help.

The code has been updated.

None of the code in your StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>( seems to extract the UserModel from the snapshot, so I'm not sure how the user profile image would be updated when there's a new document snapshot.

I am not sure what you meant.
backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
widget.userData.profileImage.toString()),
);                                                                                                 Here userData is corresponding UserModel and calls the firebase profileImage value.

How does widget.userData get set? And, more importantly, how does it get updated when the change is written to the database?

From what I understand, the stream is set for 'users' collection in Firebase. So any changes inside users will emit a new value in stream, and the UI of the StreamBuilder gets updated accordingly?

Back up a few comments there: nothing in your code uses the data from the snapshot in that stream builder. You detect errors and the absence of data, but if the snapshot has data: you do nothing with it.

okay, I replaced the entire code with cubits and blocbuilder. It works now. Thanks.

Good to hear you got it working, @M99Coder!

I think you are using wrong link in the NetworkImage.
                         return CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 75,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  snapshot.data!.docs.first['profilImage']),  <------  here made changes.
                            );


The image is being referred to the correct location. If I logout and come back to this page again, I am getting the updated image.

The image is not updating because you used widget.userData.profileImage.toString(), whenever stream builder update this The image reffered old image link, according to the provided code.

So what is the fix?
